# how can I change the outline icons in vscode to something colorless?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I'd like all the outline view/window icons (clarification: not the file icons, the stuff under "outline") to be colorless in vscode, but I can't find any themes with different and/or colorless outline icons. Is it possible to go into the vscode settings and change the icon files manually? Ie. change json settings, run a script on the file(s) to change all color codes to white or something like that?

Edit: re answer below file-icons colorless does not replace the outline icons :(

[image]

Comment: what do you mean with `window icons`

Comment: colors are defined here: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color

Comment: then create an issue at the extension repo for colorless folder icons

Comment: I mean the icons in the "subwindow"or "part of the window" with the heading "outline" in the upper left of the screen :)

Comment: Changing the settings as described in the link luuk posted worked, thanks!

Comment: that View is labelled `OUTLINE` because that is the name of your workspace, so don't call it outline icons because 30M+ VSC users don't have a folder/workspace named outline

Comment: Outline view#

The Outline view is a separate section in the bottom of the File Explorer. When expanded, it will show the symbol tree of the currently active editor. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface

Comment: There is an outline "view" included in vscode and it does have icons, it's not the same thing as the folder/workspace :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see from the comments of your question you were able to find a solution. For others' reference:

You need to update `settings.json` to include the color updates you want to make for the variables listed here: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#symbol-icons-colors under the `workbench.colorCustomizations` object.

e.g.,

```json
// settings.json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "symbolIcon.variableForeground": "#a8a8a8",
    "symbolIcon.arrayForeground": "#a8a8a8",
    "symbolIcon.booleanForeground": "#a8a8a8",
    "symbolIcon.classForeground": "#a8a8a8",
    "symbolIcon.colorForeground": "#a8a8a8",
    "symbolIcon.constantForeground": "#a8a8a8"
    ...
    ...
},
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *do not* have a colorless icon set that you want to use:

Use the [file-icons](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=file-icons.file-icons) VSCode extension and select `File Icons (Colourless)`.

---

If you *do* have colorless icons that you want to use, you can use your own icon files with the [vscode-icons](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons) VSCode extension.

From the vscode-icons [wiki](https://github.com/vscode-icons/vscode-icons/wiki/Custom):

1. Create a folder called `vsicons-custom-icons`
2. Place the folder in one of the following locations (depending on your OS):

- Windows: `C:\Users\<your_user>\AppData\Roaming\<Code Folder>\User\vsicons-custom-icons`
- Linux: `/home/<your_user>/.config/<Code Folder>/User/vsicons-custom-icons`
- Mac: `/Users/<your_user>/Library/Application Support/<Code Folder>/User/vsicons-custom-icons`

Comment: Thanks! I've tried the file icons colorless package, and I like it. But non of the file icon packages I've tried changes the outline window :/ See above for example with file icons colorless enabled

Comment: @Var87—to clarify, are you referring to icons for folders within the Outline window that still have color? BookmarkFolderNode, BookmarkEndNode, etc.? Or something different?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: Thank you for clarifying—in that case, you may have to install your own icon set.